# RegeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, babeljs, karma-babel-preprocessor

I am trying to run [Karma-babel-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-babel-preprocessor) and a straight forward ES6 generator:

```
//require('babel/polyfill');

  describe("how Generators work", function() {
    it("will allow generator functions", function() {
      /*function * numbers() {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
      };*/


      let numbers = {
        [Symbol.iterator]:function*(){
            yield 1;
            yield 2;
            yield 3;
          }
      }

      let sum = 0;

      for(n of numbers){
        sum += n;
      }

      expect(sum).toBe(6);
    });
  });
```

From this I generated my test files (ES6 => ES5) with babel:

`babel src --watch --out-dir tests`

Then I run `karma start` I get error:

> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined".

Relevant bits in karma.conf.js:

```
  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      {pattern: 'tests/*.js', included: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
            'src/*.js': ['babel']
    },
        'babelPreprocessor': {
      options: {
        sourceMap: 'inline'
      },
      filename: function(file) {
        return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
      },
      sourceFileName: function(file) {
        return file.originalPath;
      }
    },


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],
```

[Full project on github](https://github.com/pbrianmackey/ES6)

I am able to use many ES6 features including arrows.  Just no go on Generators.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While I'm taking a different approach** to using Karma with Babel in my project, I suspect you're having the same problem I was: the [Babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) is not being loaded, and so you're not getting the functionality it supports (including the custom regenerator runtime that Babel uses to make generators work).

One approach would be to find a way to include the polyfill, perhaps by feeding it to Karma via the files array:

```
files: [
  'path/to/browser-polyfill.js', // edited: polyfill => browser-polyfill per P.Brian.Mackey's answer
  ...
```

An alternate approach may be to use Babel's [runtime transformer](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime/) [*edit: on rereading the docs, this will not work unless you then browserify/webpack/etc. to process the `require()` calls created by the transformer*]; per its docs,

> The `runtime` optional transformer does three things:
>
> - Automatically requires `babel-runtime/regenerator` when you use generators/async functions.
> - Automatically requires `babel-runtime/core-js` and maps ES6 static methods and built-ins.
> - Removes the inline babel helpers and uses the `module babel-runtime/helpers` instead.

I have no experience with this, but I suspect you would do so by including the `optional: ['runtime']` option from the Babel docs in your `babelPreprocessor` config, viz.:

```
'babelPreprocessor': {
  options: {
    optional: ['runtime'],  // per http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/
    sourceMap: 'inline'
  },
...
```

(*** I'm currently using jspm + jspm-karma + some config to get the Babel polyfill to load in SystemJS; ask if relevant and I'll expound.*)

Comment: I tried both options.  Neither one worked for me.  I added `node_modules/babel/polyfill.js` and Error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`.  I believe referring to the single line in this file containing `module`.  I added more and more dir/*.js directories and just got deeper into it with nothing working.  The second option you listed seems to have no impact, same error.

Comment: Your answer is very close and certainly put me on the right track.  There are a few gotcha's so I posted an answer to help identify them.

Comment: Awesome! I've edited the polyfill path in my answer to avoid confusing others.

Answer (score 45):

**Node js Env - updated December 2015**

*This question has already been answered, please see accepted answer UNLESS running within NodeJS environment.*

If like myself, you had the same error message: **'ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined'**  but were running Babel within a NodeJS environment, then simply doing the following will likely solve your problem:

```
npm install babel-polyfill --save
```

Then insert the following require statement towards the top of the affected module to obtain required (generator) behaviour:

```
require("babel-polyfill");
```

This should be all you need, just importing the module adds required polyfill behaviour at runtime.

Comment: I was trying to get [FuseBox](http://fuse-box.org/) working to bundle a React app and I had to do this to get it working properly.

Answer (score 31):

Similar to the post by arcseldon, I was running Babel within a NodeJS environment and getting the same error message 'ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined'.  While installing babel-polyfill does work, I went with @babel/plugin-transform-runtime instead.

[@babel/plugin-transform-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime)

It needs to be installed in two ways ... first as a dev dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

and second as a production dependency:

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime
```

And then there needs to be one simple addition to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

These additions give ES6 authoring functionality without the ReferenceError.

Comment: I was trying to get some Jest unit tests to run correctly on circleci and had to use this to get them to pass.

Comment: Works with webpack 5 + babel

Answer (score 4):

I modified `karma.conf.js` to add `browser-polyfill` as **mentioned** in the [Docs Link](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/):

```
files: [
            'node_modules/babel/browser-polyfill.js',
      'test-main.js',
      {pattern: 'tests/*.js', included: true}
    ],
```

After this modification, the following unit test works in Karma:

```
  describe("how Generators work", function() {
    it("will allow generator functions", function() {
     /*function* numbers(){
       yield 1;
       yield 2;
       yield 3;
     };*///Simplified syntax does not work

      let numbers = {
        [Symbol.iterator]:function*(){
            yield 1;
            yield 2;
            yield 3;
          }
      }

      let sum = 0;

      for(let num of numbers){
        sum += num;
      }

      expect(sum).toBe(6);
    });
  });
```

Comment: how does your whole karma.conf look like?

Comment: The file to include seems to have turned into 'node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js'

Answer (score 0):

If you use **React**, adding polyfills from `create-react-app` worked for me.

```
yarn add --dev react-app-polyfill
```

Then add the following lines to `webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
  app: [
    'react-app-polyfill/ie9', // Only if you want to support IE 9
    'react-app-polyfill/stable',
    './src/index.jsx',
  ],
},
```

See more examples on the [react-app-polyfill GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill).