# Ember >2.2.0 getting regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

so I was working with an iterator inside a service with Ember. The code worked using the old style scripts I cannot use the ES2015 style

> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

```
    stuff[Symbol.iterator] = function *(){
        debugger;
        let properties = Object.keys(this);
        for(let p of properties){
            yield this[p];
        }
    };
```

I know this is because of the new '*' operator on the function. I have seen answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/28978619/24862 that describe having to load a browser-polyfill npm but I'm a little unclear how to get this to work inside the ember framework. Has anyone done this successfully? or should I just abandon until Ember supports it.

Comment: Are you talking about ember-cli?  Ember itself wouldn't have any issue with a language level syntax.

Comment: yes, sorry. I am using Ember-Cli and the code is inside a Controller or Conponent... to be honest I was copying some code in from another ES2015 test project. I can understand certain functionality not being available but since I never saw a listing I just assumed if the browser does, Ember-Cli would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## Polyfill
>
> Babel comes with a polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime and core-js. Many transformations will work without it, but for full support you may need to include the polyfill in your app.

You should now include as `ember-cli-babel` and not as `babel`. Like this:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-cli-babel': {
        includePolyfill: true
    }
}
```

Regenerator:

> This package implements a fully-functional source transformation that takes the syntax for generators/yield from ECMAScript 2015 or ES2015 and Asynchronous Iteration proposal and spits out efficient JS-of-today (ES5) that behaves the same way.

Sources: https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel and https://github.com/facebook/regenerator

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your use of Babel.js needs to include the polyfill, in your ember-cli-build.js file use:

```
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    babel: {
      includePolyfill: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure this will work, as I am 6 months further down the pipeline for this project... however since you took the time to answer it. Might as well get it off the un-answered list.