# regeneratorRuntime is not defined for nodeJS transpiled babel

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

and it is caused by

```
_asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
```

I have tried the methods in [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await) and also [RegeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976748/regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined), but have no luck.

My `.babelrc` is as below

```
{
  "presets":["latest"]
}
```

I am able to solve the problem by add `require('babel-polyfill')` however this line will throw problem if I run it with `babel-node` during development time.

Anyone faced similar problem before?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, I have experienced this problem with node 8.x with similar results in that when I add `require('babel-polyfill')` the problem goes away, but I shouldn't have to do this. It appears to be environmental.

Answer (score 1):

Add babel-polyfill to your plugins in the .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [["es2016"]],
  "plugins": ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator","babel-polyfill"],
}
```